Rails7アプリをProductionモードで起動したら一部デザインが崩れてしまう
状況
自作Railsアプリのプログラムをローカルで開発したので、動作確認のためにDocker環境上でproductionモードで起動しました。
アプリ自体は起動し、http://localhost:8000 でアクセスするとアプリ自体も表示されるのですが、一部デザインが崩れて表示されてしまいます。（CSSがうまく効かず画像が特大サイズで表示されたりします。）
developmentモードでは正常に表示されます。
Railsバージョンは7.1.4です。
試したこと
下記コマンドを実行しましたが、デザインは崩れたままでした。
docker-compose run web rails assets:precompile

以下のエラーが発生しているため、「microtip.min」ファイルがうまく読み込めていないようです。
SassC::SyntaxError: Error: File to import not found or unreadable: microtip.min. (SassC::SyntaxError)
        on line 19432:2 of stdin
>>  @import 'microtip.min';

しかし、microtip.minはassets/stylesheetsフォルダ配下に格納されており、「@import 'microtip.min'」というコードにも問題はなさそうです。microtip.minはツールチップを定義する外部ライブラリなのですが、ツールチップだけではなく、他の画像のデザインやBootstrapで定義している一部デザインも崩れている箇所があるため、他の根本的な原因があるようにも思えます。
Gemfile
developmentにしかインストールしていないgemライブラリがあるかどうか確認しましたが、開発環境に用いる一部のライブラリ以外はproductionにもインストールされているようです。
production.rb
ChatGPTに言われた通り以下のコードを色々追加してみましたが、事象は解消しませんでした。
  # 以下追加
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.debug = false
  config.public_file_server.enabled = true
  config.assets.prefix = "/assets"
  config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://localhost:8000'
  config.assets.version = '1.0'
  config.cache_store = :memory_store

解決法を教えていただけますと幸いです。

application.css内で定義している以下のコードを
 @import 'microtip.min';

以下のフルパス指定に変更したところ解決しました。
 @import 'app/assets/stylesheets/microtip.min.css';

